# Android studio if statement showing 'Incompatible types' flag

Tags: java, android, boolean

I am making a very basic practice app in Android studio that checks if the number taken from a user is a triangular number or not. Eg: 15.

The problem I am having is that the first part of my `if` statement is flagging `number` with, `Incompatible types. Required boolean. Found int`, in the Android Studio IDE.
I have set the method to expect to return a boolean value, and it does. I I'm not sure the exactly why this flag is being raised.

```
public void getInput() {
    EditText usersInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userField);
    int userInputNumber = Integer.parseInt(usersInput.getText().toString());
    System.out.println(userInputNumber);

    Numbers checkTriangular = new Numbers();
    checkTriangular.isTriangularNumber(userInputNumber);
}

class Numbers {
    public boolean isTriangularNumber(int number) {
        number = number*(number+1)/2;
        if (number) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (number)` is probably what you want to look at more closely.

Comment: inside the if statement, you need a boolean expression, not an int.

Comment: I understand that it wants a boolean. But I don't understand why when the method returns one already. If I just stick `true` in there, I have no logic. Nothing is being a evaluated

Comment: so ... based on which condition does it need to return true, and when should it return false?

Comment: It should return true if it is a triangular number, false otherwise. I tried putting `number = number*(number+1)/2;` in the if statement initially but had the same issue

Comment: You mean if the number is exact and not a decimal? Then return true?

Comment: brilliant, so you'll need something like: return isTriangularNumber(number); // isTriangularNumber returns true if number is triangular, otherwise false

Comment: here you can find information on how exactly to write that method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: @RichardC: that has nothing to do with a triangular number, so what do you need?

Comment: @Stultuske The exercise is to take a number from the user and check to see if it is a triangular number.

Comment: Then why did you say "yes" to Kristy? that is not nearly the same. I gave you all you need to solve it.

Comment: @Stultuske I gave that +1 because it cleared something up for me. I didn't mark that as the solution

Comment: @RichardC: I'm not talking about upvotes, I'm talking about your "Yes @KristyWelsch" reply here. She asked "You mean if the number is exact and not a decimal? Then return true? " so your answer should 've been "No", since that's not the same as a Triangular number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I was getting at overall.
But initially all I was after was why Android Studio was giving me, `Incompatible types. Required boolean. Found int`, which was explained.

```
class Numbers {

        int number;

        public boolean isTriangularNumber(int number) {
            int x = 1;
            int triangularNumber = 1;

            while (triangularNumber < number) {
                x++;
                triangularNumber = triangularNumber +x;

            }

            if (triangularNumber == number) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

All mysteries solved

Answer (score 0):

This will test if number is a round number.

```
public boolean isTriangularNumber(int number) {
    number = number*(number+1)/2;
    if (number % 1 == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you may want to wait until he decides what he needs. being a decimal number is not the same as being an integer without decimals

Answer (score 0):

```
if (number)
```

expects number to be a boolean.

I assume you're thinking in C where

```
if (number)
```

is a shorthand for

```
if (number !=0)
```

No such shorthand exists in java.

Answer (score 0):

My math's isn't great, however, it is my understanding that following will return true if the number is triangular (assuming `number > 0`...you can test for it with `if (number > 0)` or use `Math.abs(number)` to convert any input to a positive number):

```
public boolean isTriangularNumber(int number) {
    return (((Math.sqrt((8*number)+1)) % 1) == 0)
}
```